# Angularjs 1.4.5: animation using ng-enter not working

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-animate

I am new to AngularJS and I am working on creating fadein animation. I added all the required js files in my my header and `element.ng-enter` and `element.ng-enter-ng-enter.active` classes in css file as per documents from AngularJS. When I browse the URL, I dont get fadein effects. Here is my JSFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/o22ffaxb/).

**HTML code:**

```
<div ng-app="Dashboard">
  <div id="dashboard" ng-controller="dashboardCtrl">
    <div class="app-nav">
      <button onclick="location.href = '/';">Dashboard</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="app-nav">
      <button onclick="location.href = 'Applications';">Healthchecks</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="app-nav">
      <button>Contact US</button>
    </div>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS Script:**

```
angular.module('Dashboard', ['ngAnimate'])
  .controller('dashboardCtrl', function ($scope) {

  });
```

**CSS:**

```
#dashboard {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.app-nav {
  max-width: 350px;
  min-height: 75px !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.app-nav button:hover {
  background-color: #154995;
}

.app-nav button {
  min-width: 350px;
  min-height: 75px;
}

button.ng-enter {
  transition: 3s linear all;
  opacity: 0;
}

button.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 2;
}
```

Comment: Example from the angular documentation: http://plnkr.co/edit/VBA1j2kMOrMFMq94HOOS?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix pure javascript in your html file with angular. You should replace `onclick` with `ng-click` because then angular can inject correct class to div and show you animation

index.html

```
<div ng-app="Dashboard">
    <div id="dashboard" ng-controller="dashboardCtrl">
        <div class="app-nav">
            <button ng-click="functionOne()">Dashboard</button>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="app-nav">
            <button ng-click="functionTwo()">Healthchecks</button>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="app-nav">
            <button>Contact US</button>
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
            .module('Dashboard')
            .controller('dashboardCtrl', dashboardCtrl);

    dashboardCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'ngAnimate'];

    function dashboardCtrl($scope, ngAnimate) {

        $scope.functionOne = function () {
            // your action
        };

        $scope.functionTwo = function () {
            // your action
        };
    }

}());
```